# AngularJS, adding a scrolling directive to pick up bottom of scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is a basic directive to detect scrolling to the bottom of an iframe but it is not kicking off, do you see an issue?

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myapp').directive('textAgreement', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',    
      scope: true,
      compile: function(tElement) {
        tElement.append('<div ng-show="bottom">There is more...</div>');
        return function(scope, element) {
          var elm = element[0];        
          var check = function() {
            scope.bottom = (elm.offsetHeight + elm.scrollTop >= elm.scrollHeight);
          };
          var appliedCheck = function() {
            scope.$apply(check);
          };
          element.bind('scroll', appliedCheck);
          check();        
          $timeout(check,500);          
          }; 
      }    
    };
  });   
})();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 body-text">
        <h4>Use Agreement</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="tos" class="load-iframe">
            <iframe text-agreement id="agreeFrame" class="agree-frame" src="{{ ::trustSrcAgreementUri }}"  style="border:0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test your code becuase you didn't added something to work with but I think you are not listening correctly on  your iframe element.
Yo have to bind the event to the *document element* of the iframe.

look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279477/how-to-make-iframe-listen-to-scroll-events-as-parent-when-click-event-within-par)

Comment: I got ya, how can you reference the 'window' within an iframe based on the code above.  This is binding to the 'scroll' event of the iframe, I wonder if it is possible to create a directive to scroll on the irame.window

Comment: This is a little better, more tied to angularjs.